# Finding an asymptotic expansion for $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty t \exp(-(t-xt^{-1})^2) \ dt$ as $x\to0$.

Tags: perturbation-theory

I am looking to find the first few terms in an asymptotic expansion for the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}t
\exp\left(-\left[t-xt^{-1}\right]^{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}t
\quad\mbox{as}\quad x \to 0
$$
I am also told that Euler's constant $\gamma$ should come in useful. However, I cannot see why this is so ( Laplace's method doesn't give an expression involving $\gamma$ so I'm not sure what method to use ). I am fairly new to asymptotics, so I would appreciate a model answer that would help further my understanding of the topic. Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $x>0$, given by a CAS,
$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty t\, e^{-\left(t-\frac{x}{t}\right)^2}\,dt=x \,e^{2 x}\, K_1(2 x)$$ where appears  the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Using the expansion of the whole term, you should get
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+x+x^2 \left(\log (x)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$

To check, let $x=10^{-k}$ and the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.587746305719 & 0.583338603719 \\
 2 & 0.509647204548 & 0.509638700563 \\
 3 & 0.500994169460 & 0.500994156449 \\
 4 & 0.500099918669 & 0.500099918651 \\
 5 & 0.500009998956 & 0.500009998956 \\
 6 & 0.500000999987 & 0.500000999987 \\
 7 & 0.500000100000 & 0.500000100000 \\
 8 & 0.500000010000 & 0.500000010000 \\
 9 & 0.500000001000 & 0.500000001000
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

A better approximation would be
$$f(x)=e^{2x}\left(\frac{1}{2}+x^2 \left(\log (x)+\gamma -\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(x^3\right) \right)$$ as shown below for the same table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.583520655506 & 0.583338603719 \\
 2 & 0.509638727486 & 0.509638700563 \\
 3 & 0.500994156453 & 0.500994156449 \\
 4 & 0.500099918651 & 0.500099918651
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. Can this problem be solved in any other way? For example, by rescaling, integration by parts, Laplace's Method, Watson's Lemma etc.

Comment: @wrb98. No idea ! Sorry :-(

Answer (score 2):

**Asymptotic Expansion**

Let $2u=t-1/t$, then $t=u+\sqrt{u^2+1}$ and $tt'=2u+\frac{2u^2+1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$.
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\int_0^\infty te^{-(t-x/t)^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x\int_0^\infty te^{-x(t-1/t)^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=x\int_{-\infty}^\infty tt'e^{-4xu^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=2x\int_0^\infty\frac{2u^2+1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}e^{-4xu^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{u^2+2x}{\sqrt{u^2+4x}}e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
f(0)
&=\int_0^\infty ue^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Starting with $(1)$, we can compute
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{4x}{\left(u^2+4x\right)^{3/2}}e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac1{\left(u^2+1\right)^{3/2}}e^{-4xu^2}\mathrm{d}u\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
f'(0)
&=\int_0^\infty\frac1{\left(u^2+1\right)^{3/2}}\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=1\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, starting with $(3)$, we can compute
$$
\begin{align}
f''(x)
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{-4u^2}{\left(u^2+1\right)^{3/2}}e^{-4xu^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{-2\sqrt{u}}{\left(u+1\right)^{3/2}}e^{-4xu}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\color{#C00}{-2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-4xu}}{u+1}\,\mathrm{d}u}
+\color{#090}{2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{u+1}-\sqrt{u}}{\left(u+1\right)^{3/2}}e^{-4xu}\mathrm{d}u}\\[6pt]
&=\color{#C00}{2(\log(x)+\gamma+\log(4))}+\color{#090}{2(2-\log(4))}+O(x\log(x))\\[12pt]
&=2\log(x)+2\gamma+4+O(x\log(x))\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(2)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&\sim\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \ \ \tfrac12\ \ \ \ \ \ }^{(2)}+\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \ \ x\vphantom{\tfrac12}\ \ \ \ \ \ }^{(4)}+\overbrace{x^2\log(x)-\tfrac32x^2}^{2\log(x)}+\overbrace{(\gamma+2)x^2\vphantom{\tfrac12}}^{2\gamma+4}+O\!\left(x^3\log(x)\right)\\[6pt]
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\tfrac12+x+x^2\log(x)+\left(\gamma+\tfrac12\right)x^2+O\!\left(x^3\log(x)\right)}\tag6
\end{align}
$$

---

**Red Integral**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_x^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm{d}u
&=\int_x^\infty e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}\log(u)\\
&=-\log(x)\,e^{-x}+\int_x^\infty\log(u)\,e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\log(x)\,e^{-x}-\gamma-\int_0^x\log(u)\,e^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\log(x)\,e^{-x}-\gamma-\int_0^x\log(u)\,\mathrm{d}\left(1-e^{-u}\right)\\
&=-\log(x)\,e^{-x}-\gamma-\log(x)\left(1-e^{-x}\right)+\int_0^x\frac{1-e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\log(x)-\gamma-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k\,k!}\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-4xu}}{1+u}\,\mathrm{d}u
&=e^x\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-4xu}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=e^{4x}\int_{4x}^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}u\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-e^{4x}\left(\log(4x)+\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-4x)^k}{k\,k!}\right)\\[6pt]
&=-(\log(x)+\gamma+\log(4))+O(x\log(x))\tag8
\end{align}
$$

---

**Green Integral**

Let $u=\frac{v}{1-v}$ and $v=w^2$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{u+1}-\sqrt{u}}{\left(u+1\right)^{3/2}}\mathrm{d}u
&=\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{\frac1{1-v}}-\sqrt{\frac{v}{1-v}}}{\left(\frac1{1-v}\right)^{3/2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{(1-v)^2}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{1-\sqrt{v}}{1-v}\,\mathrm{d}v\\[6pt]
&=\int_0^1\frac{2w}{1+w}\,\mathrm{d}w\\[12pt]
&=2-\log(4)\tag9
\end{align}
$$